# How to remove the device name from the bash prompt?

Tags: macos, command-line

Is it possible to remove the device name in my shell commands to "save space"?

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ username$
```

to

```
~ username$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, BASH (the default OS X Shell) has the ability to customize the prompt in many ways.

`$PS1` is the the shell variable for the main prompt.

Try typing `echo $PS1` in the command line and it will show you how $PS1 is currently configured.

If you just want to remove the the host name you can set $PS1 to `\W \u\$` (note there is a space after the `$`) (i.e.`$PS1="\W \u\$ "`)

If you want this to happen every time you login in you will need to add `export $PS1="\W \u\$ "` to your `.bashrc` file.

There is extensive information on setting the PS1 prompt with other options in the `man bash` page.

Comment: BTW the BASH manpage (`man bash`) is huge. If you want to go through it sensibly, type: `man -t bash | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app/`. This opens a copy of the manpage in Preview (which you can then save as a pdf).